# Inconsistent date/time format when importing to R from Excel

Tags: r, excel, date, time

I've been working with an Excel file with dates in one column and the time of day in a second column. In Excel, the date column is formatted as "Date" and the time column is formatted as "Time". After trying myriad ways of importing these data from Excel into R, I finally found a way to get the data I wanted -- one column in an R data.frame of the date and time together as class POSIXct. First, when reading in the data using `read.xlsx2` from the package xlsx, I set the `colClasses` to `"numeric"` for both columns. This gives me, e.g., "16417" for the date and "0.3375000" for the time.

Second, I combined them into one column by doing this:

```
 as.POSIXct(as.Date(Data1$Date + Data1$Time,
                                  origin = "1970-01-01"), 
                          "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") + 60*60*8
```

This gives me the correct date and time (2014-12-13 08:06:00).

However, when I attempted to do the same thing with a *second* Excel file with date and time in separate columns but formatted just the same as in the first Excel file (date column formatted as "Date" and time column formatted as "Time"), I get a different result! For the second file, what in Excel was, e.g., "12/13/2014" (date column) and "8:06:00 AM" (time column) results in "41986" for the date and "0.3375000" for the time, which becomes "2084-12-14 08:06:00" in R once I add those columns together!

What's going on? Considering that people nearly always use Excel to supply me with data for analysis in R, **what's the best way to deal with importing dates and times consistently into R from Excel?** Why are the two dates different when saved in Excel and then imported into R the same way?

Comment: If your date column is `12/13/2014`, the `as.Date` format should be `%m/%d/%Y`

Comment: Read the Help Desk article in https://www.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2004-1.pdf

Comment: Actually, since I imported it as "numeric", it is `41986`. This is one of the things that is confusing to me since, in the other file, importing that same date as numeric gives me `16417`.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck: I did. That didn't resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Problem maybe Excel (on Windows)  uses Jan 1, 1900 as the Origin and not UNIX's Jan 1, 1970.  That would account for the 70 year difference.

```
as.POSIXct(as.Date(Data1$Date + Data1$Time, origin = "1900-01-01")
```

FYI: On the MacOx the origin is Jan 1, 1904.  Also 1900 did not have a leap day, but Excel(Windows) mistaken said it did.

Comment: Yes, to get around the issue, I set the origin as "1899-12-30" when converting the date for the second file, but why was that necessary? How can I predict when I'll need to use the Windows or the Unix start date?

Comment: Without looking at the original files it is hard to say.  The original data may been saved as Date fields in one case and as text in the other.

Comment: @LauraS If the date in Excel is stored as a "real Excel date", the base date should never be the UNIX start date.  You need to examine the excel file that shows this very closely to determine the problem.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld: Thank you. I'm checking closely. I still haven't deciphered the problem, but yes, I do believe it's with Excel.

Comment: @LauraS If you want to upload the file that shows the problem (removing confidential information), and post a link here, I could take a look at it.